# Read Content from a JSON file to be able to complement my url search within cypress

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, cypress

I'm currently working with some testing files that will be looking into some records that will provide me some data to be able to do a web search. However, I just want to read a specific input from my file. For the same reason, I added the following:

```
describe('Search', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
       cy.login()

     cy.fixture('latestLead.json').then(function (lead) {
            this.lead = lead
        })
     
  it('Convert Lead to an Opportunity',  () => {

   cy.readFile('cypress/fixture/latestLead.json').then(r => {
            r.forEach((item: any) => {
            cy.log(item.Id);
            });
        });
  })

})
```

My json file is the following:

```
{
  "status": 0,
  "result": {
    "totalSize": 1,
    "done": true,
    "records": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "type": "Lead",
          "url": "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Test/11111111"
        },
        "Id": "1111111111111",
        "Name": "Andres Test Test"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The main issues issue is telling me that 'any' is not right, and my cypress will not run. However, I would like to see if it is a better way to get the 'Id' from my json file. Does anyone have a better idea of how to do this?

Comment: You should target the records within result, `r.result.records.forEach()`. But the whole thing is messy. Why not use `this.lead` instead of re-reading the file? With `cy.readFile` you probably need to parse before you can access it.

Comment: How can I do that since the 'this.lead' is not letting me accessing the right input? @Sarah

Comment: What does "not letting me accessing the right input" mean?

Comment: As an example, I'm running `this.lead.result.records.Id` but it says that result is undefined

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(this.lead)`?

Comment: My idea is to run a command that will allow me to access the `Id` to make sure I can use it with my baseUrl to complement the URL search and be able to edit the content inside of that specific `Id'

Comment: @BarmyFotheringay-Phipps I'm getting back the json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably assign the fixture an alias and call that in the tests and have the execution within the `cy.get()` for the fixture. A few things to note with using fixtures: [they are only loaded once, even if data changes.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture#Loaded-just-once)

```
describe('Search', function () {
    cy.fixture('latestLead.json').as('latestLead')

    it('Convert Lead to an Opportunity',  () => {
        cy.get('@latestLead').then((data) => {
            var ids = []
            data.result.records.forEach((record) => {
                ids.push(record.Id)
            })
            // whatever you need to do with the ids
        })
    })
})
```

If you will only ever have the one object in the `records` array, you could bypass the `.forEach()` and just reference the variable directly (`data.results.records[0].Id`).

Also, are you using types anywhere else? I'm not sure why you would set `item: any` unless you were using types.